# Can python open SA:MP interface and autoconnect to a server?

Tags: python, interface, game-engine, cleo

I searched over the internet but I didn't find anything concise.
I want, if is possible, with python to open the SA:MP(GTA San Andreas MultiPlayer) interface and auto-connect to a server. For those who know the game, GTA San Andreas MultiPlayer, exist any possibility to do that? Automatically?
I succed open the SA:MP app, but i don't know how to get the 'Connect' button.
[www.sa-mp.com](http://www.sa-mp.com) - here is the interface of the game i talked about and here is a photo of the game interface.
[SA:MP interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tpxX.png)

Thank in advance for your time to read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run a samp.exe with attributes
-h  -  host
-p  -  port
-n  -  your nickname

Like this `samp.exe -h="127.0.0.1" -p="7777" -n="administrator"`
or this `samp.exe 127.0.0.1:7777" -n="administrator"`